# Shortest program to split special array

Tags: code-golf, math, array

## Background

Imagine, you have a big array `A`, which is mostly zeroes, but contains a short subarray `B` which has only strictly positive entries. For instance:

```
|              A              |
[0   0   0   0   1   2   3   0]
               |     B     |
```

Now say, we split the array `A` into consecutive subarrays of length `d` (with a shorter final array, if the `d` doesn't divide the length of `A`). For `d = 3`:

```
[0   0   0   0   1   2   3   0]
           |           |
[0   0   0] [0   1   2] [3   0]
```

And now sum up each of those arrays:

```
[0 3 3]
```

And discard zero sums:

```
[3 3]
```

## The Challenge

You're to write a function which prints that final array of sums in any convenient array format, given the following 5 parameters (or any subset thereof, if you don't need all of them):

- The small array `B`.
- The size of the small array `B` (`3` in the above example).
- The *size* of the big array `A` (`8` in the above example).
- The index where the small array begins (`4` in the above example).
- The length `d` of the subarrays (`3` in the above example).

## The Rules

- You are not allowed to construct the big array `A` explicitly!
- You are not allowed to construct any of the subarrays of length `d` explicitly!
- That means you have to get the computation directly from the `B` and the other parameters at your disposal!

Fewest characters wins!

Comment: Can we remove/omit the inputs we don't need? As far as I can tell, I don't need `size_bigarray` or `size_smallarray` at all.

Comment: yes if you don't need it

Comment: May we construct the mini arrays that overlap with `small_array`? In your example, that would only be `[0,1,2], 3,0]`. Or none at all?

Comment: no mini arrays should be constructed

Comment: I tried to reword the spec a bit, to make the actual problem a bit more visual in the first place. Feel free to roll back the edit if you don't like it, it's just a suggestion!

Comment: @MartinBüttner Are A and B supposed to be switched in the first code block?

Comment: @hsl oops, yes...

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>34 32</s> 28 characters

```
{"ɚ광䃻噣攍圍숵셳ﶓ訙➰鑓쥾"2G#b126b:c~}
```

This is a compressed form of the following 31 bytes solution

```
{:D%0a*\+0\{+U):UD={0:U}*}%0-p}
```

<s>This can be golfed further.</s>

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Input is in format of `[small_array] index_where_small_array_begins divisor`

For example:

```
[1 2 3] 5 3{"ɚ광䃻噣攍圍숵셳ﶓ訙➰鑓쥾"2G#b126b:c~}~
```

will give output

```
[1 5]
```

Explanation (outdated):

```
{                                   "Begin of function block";
 :D                                 "Store the divisor in D";
   %                                "Calculate index_where_small_array_begins%divisor";
    0a*                             "Get an array of 0 on length above number";
       \+                           "Prepend it to the small_array";
         _,{            }*          "Run this code block length(small_array) times";
            0\                      "Put 0 before small_array. This 0 marks the"
                                    "current sum of the current mini_array";
              {      }D*            "Run this code block divisor times";
               0+                   "Add 0 at the end of mini array";
                 (                  "Take out the first element from the mini array";
                  @                 "Rotate the stack to get current sum on top";
                   +                "Add the first element to the current sum";
                    \               "Swap to put current mini_array on top of stack";
                          ;]        "Pop the residual array and wrap the sums in an array";
                            0-p     "Remove 0 and print the sum_of_mini_arrays_array";
                               }    "End of function block";
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>30</s> 28 characters

```
{"ᘏ阋Յ꺂࠻䚉누୛伪"6e4b127b:c~}
```

(SE may have swallowed some unprintable characters. Please copy the code [from this character counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%7B%22%11%E1%98%8F%E9%98%8B%D5%85%EA%BA%82%E0%A0%BB%E4%9A%89%EE%90%A6%EB%88%84%E0%AD%9B%EE%89%B1%E4%BC%AA%EE%9F%8B%226e4b127b%3Ac~%7D).)

Yay for counting by characters and Unicode packing. The above string is converted to character codes, interpreted as base-2<sup>16</sup>, converted to base-129, and converted back to characters, and evaluated, to give the actual code (measuring 30 bytes):

```
{:M%0a*\+{0\{_0a?(@+\}M*}h;]p}
```

This is a block, the closest thing to a function in CJam. It expects the small array, the offset, and the divisor on the stack. You can use it like

```
[1 2 3]4 3{"    ড숺ꤪ洽ὦ﮻ڤ綃掖迓湯"2G#b129b:c~}~
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

### Explanation

```
:M                           "Store divisor in M.";
  %                          "Take offset modulo divisor to get R.";
   0a                        "Push [0].";
     *                       "Repeat to get R zeros.";
      \+                     "Preprend to small array.";
        {              }h    "Repeat while... leaves condition on the stack.";
         0\                  "Put a 0 underneath the array to initialise sum.";
           {        }M*      "Run the block M times.";
            _0a?             "Replace the list by [0] if it's empty.";
                (            "Split off first element.";
                 @           "Pull up current sum.";
                  +\         "And and pull list back to the top.";
                         ;   "Remove leftover empty list.";
                          ]  "Wrap sums in array.";
                           p "Print string representation to STDOUT.";
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/) - 30 <s>32</s>

**Edit**: Fixed an error with mini array size 1 or very large offset.

```
D:GHYKm0GFNG~@K%/HYlGN~H1)RfTK
```

Defines a function `:` that takes `small_array`, `index_where_small_array_begins` and `divisor` as arguments. You can call it like:

```
:[1 2 3) 5 3
```

Returns: `[1, 5]`

[Try it online](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

Explanation:

```
D:GHY                            : Define :
     Km0G                        : Make K an array of len(G) zeroes
         FNG             )       : for N in small_array
            ~@K%/HYlGN           : Add N to K[floor_div(H,Y)%len(G)]
                      ~H1        : Increment H
                          RfTK   : Return K without any zeroes
```

Comment: You can change `*]0lG` to `m0G`.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks, that's good to know :)

Comment: @isaacg I've also noticed in a few recent problems that pyth kinda loses out in some golf problems because it doesn't automatically mod indexing by the length of the collection. I looked at the source code, and this doesn't look easy to change, but it might be a good idea ;) (you might also then be able to overload @ with something else... ;p )

Comment: The only issue would be that assigning to a list could no longer use the same character as a lookup. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) 58

Function with 3 parameters
- b is the small array
- i is the index where the small array begins
- d is the dimension of the subarrays

(t is used just as a local variable)

```js
 F=(b,i,d,t=[])=>b.map((v,p)=>t[p=(p+i%d)/d|0]=v+~~t[p])&&t
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
F([1,2,3],4,3)
```

*Output*

```
[ 3, 3 ]
```