# Create an array with repeated numbers

Tags: code-golf, array, open-ended-function

## Challenge

Your task in this question is to write a program or a named function which takes a positive integer `n` (greater than 0) as input via STDIN, ARGV or function arguments and outputs an array via STDOUT or function returned value.

**Sounds simple enough ? Now here are the rules**

- The array will only contain integers from `1` to `n`
- Each integer from `1` to `n` should be repeated `x` times where `x` is the value of each integer.

*For example:*

Input:

```
5
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

The array may or may not be sorted.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so winner is shortest code in bytes.

**Bonus**

Multiply your score by `0.5` if no two adjacent integers in your output array are same.

For example for `n = 5`, one such configuration would be

```
[5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## APL, 4 characters

[`/⍨⍳⎕`](http://tryapl.org/index.dyalog?a=/%u2368%u23735&run)

How it works:

`⎕` reads user input.  As for output, APL by default prints the result from every line.

`⍳n` is the integers from 1 to `n`.  Example: [`⍳3`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u23733&run)`←→ 1 2 3`

`/` means *replicate*.  Each element from the right argument is repeated as many times as specified by its corresponding element from the left argument.  Example: [`2 0 3/'ABC'`](http://tryapl.org/?a=2%200%203/%27ABC%27&run)`←→ 'AACCC'`

`⍨` is the *commute operator*.  When it occurs to the right of a function, it modifies its behaviour, so it either swaps the arguments (`A f⍨ B ←→ B f A`, hence "commute") or provides the same argument on both sides (`f⍨ A ←→ A f A`, a "selfie").  The latter form is used in this solution.

---

Bonus:

[`6-∊⌽⍳¨⍳⎕`](http://tryapl.org/?a=6-%u220A%u233D%u2373%A8%u23735&run) (8 characters, [thanks @phil-h](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42536/create-an-array-with-repeated-numbers#comment-100978))

[`⍳5`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u23735&run) (iota five) is `1 2 3 4 5`.

[`⍳¨ ⍳5`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2373%A8%20%u23735&run) (iota each iota five) is `(,1)(1 2)(1 2 3)(1 2 3 4)(1 2 3 4 5)`, a vector of vectors.  *Each* (`¨`) is an operator, it takes a function on the left and applies it to each item from the array on the right.

`⌽` reverses the array, so we get `(1 2 3 4 5)(1 2 3 4)(1 2 3)(1 2)(,1)`.

`∊` is *enlist* (a.k.a. *flatten*).  Recursively traverses the argument and returns the simple scalars from it as a vector.

Comment: How about a 4-character _expression_? `/⍨⍳n`

Comment: As you wish, sir, I've updated the text.  But surely your objection must apply to other solutions that are not wrapped in functions?

Comment: If you write a full program, no need for a function name. But if you write a function, it has to be named. Most of the answers here are full programs (who read from STDIN and output to STDOUT) and all of which are functions, have names.

Comment: An expression is a full program.

Comment: A expression is not a full program if it requires you to edit the expression before running it. (for instance , to run your initial expression, one would have to add `f←` before and `5` after the expression)

Comment: I was referring to `/⍨⍳n` without the `f←` and `5`.  And, of course, instead of `n` I can use `⎕` which means "ask the user for input".

Comment: Oh, if that was a full program taking input from user/STDIN and outputting/printing to STDOUT, then its fine. Obviously, I do not understand APL that much :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that APL by default prints the result of every expression, so the STDOUT bit is covered.  Quad (`⎕`) asks for user input and evaluates it, so if the user types a number, `⎕` will return that number.  Unfortunately this can't be tested at tryapl.org as it runs in a restricted environment and `⎕` is not available, but I've seen APL solutions to other challenges by other people that use `⎕` for input.

Comment: The question said bytes. Assuming you're using UTF-8, this is 10 bytes.

Comment: Dyalog APL comes in two flavours: "Classic" and "Unicode".  The Classic version has existed for decades, since before the Unicode standard appeared, and uses a custom byte-per-character encoding for the APL character set.  It is still supported, though its use is discouraged.  So, I'd like to use this as an excuse.  More broadly, I think in golfing we should be counting characters, not bytes.  The fact that the lowest code points in Unicode are occupied by the English-centric ASCII is a historical accident that shouldn't matter today.  Interestingly, APL was conceived before ASCII came out.

Comment: @ngn [counting chars is not a good idea](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41825/31625), as answers will generally become alphabet soup decodes. APL chars are counted as bytes because that encoding exists; this is well established on this site. This works with any byte encoding that existed prior to the question's asking.

Comment: @ngn: Can you explain your bonus answer? Because it can be done via: 5 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 5 4 3 5 4 5 or 6 minus each of 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1, which feels like it is not far from your initial answer.

Comment: @phil-h Excellent idea, thank you!  So, it can be done in 8 characters ([`6-∊⌽⍳¨⍳⎕`](http://tryapl.org/?a=6-%u220A%u233D%u2373%A8%u23735&run)) instead of my complicated 11...  I'll update the answer and add an explanation later today.

Answer (score 11):

## Ruby (recursive), 41 bytes * 0.5 = 20.5

```
def n(n,i=1);i>n ?[]:n(n,i+1)+[*i..n];end
```

Or using a lambda (as recommended by histocrat and Ventero): 34 bytes * 0.5 = 17

```
r=->n,i=n{i>0?[*i..n]+r[n,i-1]:[]}
```

(call using `r[argument]`)

Comment: That's a really cool solution. You can save some bytes by making it a lambda instead of a method (`n=->x,i=1{...n[x,i+1]...`) and a few more with `[*i..n]`.

Comment: By inverting the logic, you can drop the whitespace in the ternary: `r=->n,i=n{i>0?[*i..n]+r[n,i-1]:[]}`

Answer (score 11):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes * 0.5 = 4.5

```
smrhQhdUQ
```

With help from @FryAmTheEggman

[Try it online.](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

---

### Explanation

```
s             reduce + on list
 m            map
  rhQhd       lambda d: reversed(range(d+1, Q+1)), over
       UQ     range(Q)
```

where `Q` is the input.

Comment: Shouldn't have helped you :D

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 31 characters = 15.5 score

```
f n=[y|x<-[n,n-1..1],y<-[x..n]]
```

#### 27 characters without the bonus

```
f n=[x|x<-[1..n],_<-[1..x]]
```

[Beaten by Proud Haskeller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/42577/revisions)

Comment: your first solution is not correct.  A possible fix is `g n = [y|x<-[n,n-1..1],y<-[x..n]]`

Comment: @karakfa oops :-/ and thanks for the fix

Comment: My Haskell answer is just a tad lower than yours

Comment: Should I link to it from my solution, to promote it?

Comment: @JanDvorak I would like to, actually...

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 53 bytes * 0.5 = 26.5

```py
i=n=input()
x=[]
while i:x+=range(i,n+1);i-=1
print x
```

Shamelessly borrowed @VisualMelon's idea

Answer (score 7):

## C, 22 = 44 bytes * 0.5

The function `h` takes two parameters. The first is an `int` specifying *n*. The second is an `int*` which is the output buffer.

```
h(n,o)int*o;{for(n&&h(~-n,o+=n);*--o=n--;);}
```

**Test program**

```
main(){
int wow[999],*i;
memset(wow,0,sizeof(wow));
h(6, wow);
for(i=wow;*i;i++)printf("%d ", *i);
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Please explain?

Comment: @bacchusbeale Ok.. It recursively writes descending sequences from n to 0. Shorter sequences are written sooner, at a deeper level of recursion. If the argument n is 0, then n is falsey so there is no recursion, and only a 0 is written, which serves to mark the end of the array.

Answer (score 7):

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) - <s>15</s> 10 * .5 = 5

```
smr-QdhQUQ
```

[Try it online.](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

Expects input on stdin. Independently discovered algorithm. Thanks @Sp3000 for helping me stick the last Q in there :P Also, irony? XD

Explanation:

```
Q=eval(input())       : implicit
s                     : The sum of...
 m      UQ            : map(...,range(Q))
  r-QdhQ              : range(Q-d,Q+1)
```

Comment: Nice solution. Is there ever a situation in which Pyth _wouldn't_ win code golf? :)

Comment: @Alex Depending on the nature of the problem, stack based golfing languages (Golfscript, CJam) can cream it, it can also lose to library stuff (*cough* bash *cough*) ;)

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 34 bytes * 0.5 = 17

```
0%n=[]
i%n=[i..n]++(i-1)%n
g n=n%n
```

That's the first time I've ever used Haskell for golfing. Call with `g <number>`.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>12</s> 15 bytes * 0.5 = 7.5

```
li_,f{),f-W%~}`
```

This is full STDIN-to-STDOUT program. It concatenates increasing suffixes of the `1 ... n` range, which ensures that no two adjacent numbers are identical.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 5):

## C# - 81 (161bytes * 0.5)

Simple job in C#, hopefully gets the no-neibouring-numbers bonus. Reads an int from stdin, writes out an array like the example to stdout.

```
class P{static void Main(){int n=int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine()),m=n-1,i;var R="["+n;for(;m-->0;)for(i=m;i++<n;)R+=", "+i;System.Console.WriteLine(R+"]");}}
```

More readable:

```
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int n=int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine()),m=n-1,i;
        var R="["+n;
        for(;m-->0;)
            for(i=m;i++<n;)
                R+=", "+i;
        System.Console.WriteLine(R+"]");
    }
}
```

Examples output:

```
n = 5
[5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I'm really trying to figure out a shorter C# solution but I just can't seem to get it... well done

Comment: You could create a var of System.Console maybe

Comment: @MarkKnol `System.Console` is static, you can't assign it to a variable, but in C# 6 or whatever is next, you will be able to do `using System.Console;` (`using System;` doesn't pay in this instance), not sure how I feel about this feature, will affect a lot of old golf questions for this reason precisely ;)

Comment: @VisualMelon Unless my math is wrong, `using System;` is 13 bytes and `System.`x2 is 14 bytes. You're saving 1 byte by using the using statement :)

Comment: @IchabodClay quite right, how embarrassing... I'll change that if I do anymore golfing on this, 1byte probably doesn't warrant an edit ;)

Comment: @IchabodClay it gets worse, `using C=System.Console` saves 3 bytes, and is probably what @MarkKnol meant (sorry!), shameful negligence on my part.

Comment: Also, according to the rules, you could just have the method itself instead of creating a complete program. Something like... [this](http://pastebin.com/w7P3GsJr). (114 bytes with whitespaces and such removed. 57 bytes with bonus.)

Comment: @IchabodClay indeed; I prefer submitting full programs to functions, no good reason, IO just seems like part of the fun (I don't tend to use argv, either). Feel free to post a better scoring answer without these daft constraints!

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + coreutils, 28/2 = 14

[Shamelessly stealing @pgy's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42555/11259) and golfing:

```
seq -f"seq %g $1" $1 -1 1|sh
```

---

## Pure bash (no coreutils), 30/2 = 15

Eval, escape and expansion hell:

```
eval eval echo \\{{$1..1}..$1}
```

Answer (score 5):

### GolfScript (14 bytes * 0.5 = score 7)

```
 ~:x,{~x),>~}%`
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc1JwoKfjp4LHt%2BeCksPn59JWA%3D)

I think this is probably similar to some existing answers in that it builds up the array `concat( [n], [n-1, n], [n-2, n-1, n], ..., [1, 2, ..., n] )`

Sadly I wasn't able to golf any further the arguably more elegant:

```
~:x]{{,{x\-}/}%}2*`
```

which puts the input `x` into an array and then twice applies `{,{x\-}/}%`, which maps each element in an array to a count down of that many elements from `x`.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 14 = 28 bytes / 2

```
f n=n:[1..n-1]>>= \r->[r..n]
```

example output:

```
>f 5
[5,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,4,5]
```

## 24 bytes without the bonus:

```
f n=[1..n]>>= \r->[r..n]
```

Comment: could `=<<` help avoid the whitespace? I feel like it could, but I'd be surprised if you hadn't already considered that.

Comment: @JanDvorak If I would have used `=<<` I would need parentheses for the lambda

Comment: I'm  confused on when exactly lambdas need parentheses. Does the lambda header have the same fixity as `>>=`?

Comment: @JanDvorak They have no fixity; I'm not sure how accurate this rule is, but lambdas can only appear where operators can't (disregarding sections): after `(`, `[`, `=`, `,`, after any operators, and the like

Comment: I guess neither lambdas nor operators can appear as patterns? `let \x->y = (2+) in (x,y)` seems kinda impossible.

Comment: @JanDvorak Operators can, if you consider function declarations as patterns. Remember `let 2*5=1 in 2*5`?

Comment: @JanDvorak And operators which are constructors can be patterns: `data M=Int :- Int ; let a :- b = ...`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, ES6, 41 bytes

```js
f=i=>[...Array(i).fill(i),...i?f(--i):[]]
```

This creates a function `f` which can be called like `f(6)` and it returns the required array.

This uses a recursive approach, where each iteration creates an array of `i` elements all valued `i` and concatenates an array returned by `f(i-1)` with stopping condition of `i==0`.

Works on latest Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

## vba, 76*0.5=38

```
Sub i(q)
For Z=1 To q:For x=q To Z Step -1:Debug.?x;",";:Next:Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you can lose 1 (0.5, technically) byte(s) by condensing `For Z=1 To` to `For Z=1To`

Comment: you can also condense `Next:Next` to `Next x,Z`

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 * 0.5 = 13

-8 bytes thanks to @att.

```
Join@@Range[#,Range@#,-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73ys/M8/BISgxLz01WlkHTDso6@gaxqr9DyjKzCtxSHOw/A8A)

Comment: 7 years late, but [26 * 0.5](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73ys/M8/BISgxLz01WlkHTDso6@gaxqr9DyjKzCtxSHOw/A8A) :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haxe](http://Haxe.org), 53 bytes

```
function l(v)return[for(i in 0...v)for(j in 0...i)i];
```

Works with l(6); because of array comprehension.
Test online http://try.haxe.org/#741f9

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 × 0.5 = 1.5 bytes

```
rRF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/78oyO3///@mAA)

### Explanation

```
rRF
r      Range from {input} to 
 R       each number from 1 to {input}
  F    Flatten
```

For example, with input 3, the `rR` gives us a range from 3 to 1 (i.e. `[3, 2, 1]`, then a range from 3 to 2 (i.e. `[3, 2]`), then a range from 3 to 3 (i.e. `[3, 3]`). Flattening that gives `[3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]`), which meets the problem specifications and has no adjacent numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes * 0.5 = 2

```
Σ↔ḣṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARUA6v9odXNr///Oo@KGlOG4o@G5q////zU)

#### Explanation

```
Σ↔ḣṫ
   ṫ    range from input to 1, [5,4,3,2,1]
  ḣ     prefixes, [[5],[5,4],[5,4,3]...]
 ↔      reverse,  [[5,4,3,2,1],[5,4,3,2]...]
Σ       concat,   [5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2...]
```

Comment: read the rules again ;)

Answer (score 2):

## perl ,26 bytes

```
for(1..$n){print"$_ "x$_;}
```

Comment: Please post your score. Also, since this is code golf, you can save bytes by removing the extra spaces and the definition of `$n`.

Comment: This doesn't run for me under Perl 6.

Comment: @Alex , what is the error , works under 5.10

Comment: `Unable to parse postcircumfix:sym<{ }>, couldn't find final '}' at line 3`. Tried it on ideone.com.

Comment: @Alex , try this : C:\Windows\system32>perl -e "$n=5;for(1..$n){print qq($_ )x$_;};"
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5

Comment: Doesn't work on ideone.com, which uses Perl 6, but it works on my local machine, which is running Perl 5. Your original also works on my local machine. It probably doesn't matter much, but if you felt so inclined, you could specify Perl 5 in your post. Anyway, nice work.

Comment: You should print in the following format : `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` . Not space separated values

Answer (score 2):

### R, 44 *.5 = 22

```
f=function(n){r=0;for(i in 1:n)r=c(r,n:i);r}
```

A quick test

```
> f(1)
[1] 1
> f(2)
[1] 2 1 2
> f(3)
[1] 3 2 1 3 2 3
> f(4)
 [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

Comment: What ? No TSQL ?

Comment: @Optimizer maybe later:)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, ES6, 66 bytes * 0.5 = 33

```
f=i=>(g=n=>[...Array(n).fill().map((v,x)=>i-x),...n?g(n-1):[]])(i)
```

Building on [Optimizer's recursive approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42541/7796), we can build descending runs of decreasing length, like `[4,3,2,1, 4,3,2, 4,3, 4]`.

Instead of making same-value subarrays with `Array(i).fill(i)`, we make `undefined`-filled subarrays of the appropriate length with `Array(n).fill()` and then change the values to a descending run using `.map((v,x)=>i-x)`. Also, we define and recurse over an inner function `g`; the outer function `f` exists only to store the value of `i` while `g` recurses.

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL, 176 * 0.5 = 88

Since you seemed to miss the T-SQL @Optimizer, here it is in all it's verbose glory :).

A couple of function options, a Scalar and a Inline Table Valued function.  The Scalar function uses while loops to recurse and returns a string of numbers, where the Inline Table Valued function uses a recursive CTE for a sequence and returns a table.  Of course these will never be competitive, so I haven't spent a lot of time golfing.

**Inline Table Valued Function, 176 * .5**

```
CREATE FUNCTION F(@ INT)RETURNS TABLE RETURN WITH R AS(SELECT @ N UNION ALL SELECT N-1FROM R WHERE N>0)SELECT B.N FROM R CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(R.N)N FROM R A ORDER BY N DESC)B
```

Called as follows

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.F(5)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4f86/1/0) example

**Scalar Function, 220 * .5**

```
CREATE FUNCTION G(@ INT)RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)AS BEGIN DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX),@N INT=1,@I INT,@C INT WHILE @N<=@ BEGIN SELECT @I=@N,@C=@ WHILE @C>=@I BEGIN SELECT @S=CONCAT(@S+',',@C),@C-=1 END SET @N+=1 END RETURN @S END
```

Called as follows

```
SELECT dbo.G(5)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00b75/2/0) example

Answer (score 2):

#### JavaScript(readable), 131 bytes

I'm new to Code Golf so this isn't the best

```
function f(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

#### JavaScript(less readable), 87 bytes

Minified using [jscompress.com](http://jscompress.com)

```
function f(e){var t=[];for(var n=1;n<=e;n++){for(var r=0;r<n;r++){t.push(n)}}return t}
```

Answer (score 2):

## TECO, 25 bytes * 0.5 = 12.5

```
a\+1%a%b<qauc-1%b<-1%c=>>
```

The above barely beats the non-bonus version at 13 bytes:

```
a\%a<%b<qb=>>
```

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>114</s> 99 * 0.5 = 49.5 bytes

*(With a little help from VisualMelon's answer) Edit: and James Webster's comment*

```
int[]A(int n){int m=n,i,c=0;var a=new int[n*(n+1)/2];while(m-->0)for(i=m;i++<n;)a[c++]=i;return a;}
```

*Ungolfed:*

```
int[] FooBar(int n)
{
    int altCounter = n, i, arrayCounter = 0;
    var returnArray = new int[n * (n + 1) / 2];
    while(m-->0)
        for(i = altCounter; i++ < n; )
            returnArray[arrayCounter++]=i;
    return returnArray;
}
```

---

<s>There is an unsafe version that I shamelessly took from feersum's C answer, but I'm not 100% sure it fits within the rules since you have to allocate the memory before calling the method.</s>

**C# (unsafe), 82 * 0.5 = 41 bytes**

```
unsafe void A(int n,int*p){int*z=p;int m=n,i;while(m-->0)for(i=m;i++<n;)z++[0]=i;}
```

Called as follows:

```
int n = 5, length = (int)((n / 2f) * (n + 1));
int* stuff = stackalloc int[length];
int[] stuffArray = new int[length];
A(n, stuff);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(stuffArray), stuffArray, 0, stuffArray.Length);
//stuffArray == { 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

Per VisualMelon's suggestion (thanks!), the unsafe code can be re-made with safe code which reduces the size even further! Still poses the question if the creation of the final result array is allowed to be done outside of the method.

**C#, 72 * 0.5 = 36 bytes**

```
void A(int n,int[]p){int z=0,m=n,i;while(m-->0)for(i=m;i++<n;)p[z++]=i;}
```

Comment: Nice work! For the per-allocated version, it's much cheaper to go safe and pass it the `int[]` straight off `void A(int n,int[]p){int z=0,m=n,i;while(m-->0)for(i=m;i++<n;)p[z++]=i;}` - I would agree it's probably a bit iffy, regarding the rules ;)

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a local pointer for the unsafe version, which cuts a good 8bytes out. Also, I might be missing the point, but should the last line of the unsafe calling code be `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(stuff), stuffArray, 0, length);` ?

Comment: @VisualMelon That's what I get for not rechecking the names of variables after I rename them. Thanks for the heads up :D. Edited the answer to account for the shorter version in your comment.

Comment: You can chop a little off the safe version by inlining the length `var a=new int[(int)((n/2f)*(n+1))];` I think that takes it down to 109

Comment: One more off by rewriting the calc as: `(n*(n+1)/2)`

Comment: @JamesWebster The outer parentheses can also be done away with. 2 more bytes! Thanks for the hints, I'll add them to the answer!

Comment: Are you sure that will be casting what you need @IchabodClay. I think I played around with that, but was left with integer division

Comment: @JamesWebster It should be fine, since `n * (n + 1)` is evaluated first, it will always be an even number that is divided by 2.

Comment: It's not though.. BODMAS/BIDMAS/etc, whichever you use... The division is done first.

Comment: @JamesWebster According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (near the bottom), operations are performed left to right. So, multiplication would be performed before division in this case.

Comment: That's interesting!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes * 0.5 = 2

```
L.s˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR6/49Jz//00B)

```
L                             # Inclusive range
 .s                           # Suffixes
   ˜                          # Flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>116</s> 115 + 33 = 148 bytes

Not the shortest code, but... it works anyway :P

```c#
int[]l(int m){List<int>i=new List<int>();for(int j=1;j<=m;j++){for(int x=0;x<j;x++){i.Add(j);}}return i.ToArray();}
```

Requires this at the top of the file (33 bytes):

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Un-golfed version:

```c#
int[] RepatedNumberList(int m)
{
    List<int> intList = new List<int>();
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < j; x++)
        {
            intList.Add(j);
        }
    }
    return initList.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Bash with seq, expr and xargs = 59 / 2 = 29.5

Save it and run with the number as the first argument.

```
seq $1|xargs -n1 seq|xargs -n1 expr $1 + 1 -|sed 1d;echo $1
```

Comment: Great idea!  [I stole it and golfed it significantly](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42557/11259)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 23 * 0.5 = 11.5

```
   f=.-;@(<@|.@i."0@>:@i.)
   f 5
5 4 5 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

## J, 11

```
   f=.#~@i.@>:
   f 5
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: `23 * 0.5` is `11.5`, not `10.5`.

Comment: @ProgramFOX good catch. Are you going to edit, or should I? Not a great reason to downvote IMO.

Comment: @JanDvorak Just edited it. And I didn't downvote, I upvoted it even before I saw the mistake.

Comment: Now that the mistake has been fixed, should the bonus solution be moved to the bottom?

Comment: `-1` Byte: `f=.-[:;<@|.@i."0@>:@i.`, making the scores equal!

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript6, 67 * 0.5 = 33.5 bytes

```
f=n=>{a=[],b=0;while(c=n+b,n--){while(c-b)a.push(c--);b++}return a}
```

Pretty happy with this one...It's about a quarter the size of my original.

`f(4)` returns:

```
[ 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4 ]
```

*Old answer:*

```
f=i=>{a=b=Array;while(i)a=a.concat(b.apply(null,b(i)).map(e=>i)),i--;return a}
```

This is my first shot at code golf...I still want to get that 0.5x bonus. Any suggestions are welcomed!

Called with f(n).

Comment: You must be pretty new to JavaScript it self :) . (1) Remove brackets around argument `d`, (2) `a=b=c=[]` in for declaration part, (3) `c[a].map(e=>a)` (4) `b.push(...c)`

Comment: I made a shorter version before reading your comment, which I'll put in my post.

My experience with JS is mostly limited to DOM/style manipulation for simple web apps...and I've hardly used any of the new ES6 features until today.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 29 (58 * 0.5)

**Edit** remove ; thx @Optimizer

```js
Q=o=>(m=>{for(n=o,r=[];n>m||++m<(n=o);)r.push(n--)})(0)||r
```

**Test** in FireFox/FireBug console

```
Q(9)
```

*Output*

```
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 9]
```

**Ungolfed**

```js
Q=o=>{
  for(m=0,r=[];m<o;++m)
    for(n=o;n>m;)
      r.push(n--);
  return r
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 108 bytes * 0.5 = 54

```
List<int> f(int n){var r=new List<int>();int m=n-1,i;r.Add(n);for(;m-->0;)for(i=m;i++<n;)r.Add(i);return r;}
```

Thanks to VisualMelon for doing the hard work! I thought I'd try to squeeze it down as much as possible.

(114 bytes * 0.5 = 57, if you insist on using .ToArray() to return int[])

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 4 bytes

**Solution:**

```
&!1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X03RUNv0/38A)

**Examples:**

```
&!1+5
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5
&!1+6
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

**Explanation:**

```
&!1+ / the solution
  1+ / add one to the input, 1+5 => 6
 !   / til, !6 => 0 1 2 3 4 5
&    / where, &0 1 2 3 4 5 => 1 2 2 3 3 3...
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes ÷ 2 = 26.5

```
lambda n:[n-i%-~n%(i//n-~n)for i in range(n*~n//2,0)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXMSc5NSEhXyrKLzdDNVdevyVDUy9fXzgAzNtPwihUyFzDyFosS89FSNPK26PH19Ix0DzViI5v0FRZl5JRppGgaaOmkahiDCCESYgggzTU2IqgULIDQA)

##### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) version, 51 bytes ÷ 2 = 25.5

```
lambda n:[n-i%-~n%(i/n-~n)for i in range(n*~n/2,0)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHiNNuYpaUlaboWN41zEnOTUhIV8qyi83QzVXXr8lQ1MvXzgLRmWn6RQqZCZp5CUWJeeqpGnlZdnr6RjoFmLETr_oKizLwSjTQNA02dNA1DEGEEIkxBhJmmJkTVggUQGgA)

This uses ranges like many other answers here but groups them in pairs (longest,shortest);(2nd longest,2nd shortest) etc. That way we can use a closed form expression inside a flat loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, 35 * 0.5 = 17.5 bytes

```
[ [1,b] tail-clump reverse concat ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxDsIwDAXQvaf4B4BIDCzlAIiFBTFVHYxlQkTqBsdBcPrAm9@d2Ffr18vpfByxkD@CkUapiLa2kjQG@bhRxVNMJaPKq4nyPxQT92@xpI7DMOz7hGm3uc1wSnnLuS0FJm@xKuBVmRxzZ8oZof8A)

```
           ! 5
[1,b]      ! { 1 2 3 4 5 }
tail-clump ! { { 1 2 3 4 5 } { 2 3 4 5 } ... }
reverse    ! { { 5 } { 4 5 } { 3 4 5 } ... }
concat     ! { 5 4 5 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 44 bytes

```javascript
y=x=>x-1?y(x-1).concat(Array(x).fill(x)):[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v9K2wtauQtfQvlIDSGrqJefnJSeWaDgWFSUCRTT10jJzcoC0plW0Yex/oGRxfk6qXk5@ukalhomm5n8A)

Could probably be golfed more and probably similar to some other answers but might as well post it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>8</s> <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
ƛẋ;f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwixpvhuos7ZiIsIiIsIjUiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
ƛẋ;f
ƛ    # mapping lambda
 ẋ   # Repeat
  ;  # end lambda
   f # flatten
```

Comment: I think you mean [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwixptTKjviiJFmIiwiIiwiNSJd)

Comment: Also, [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwixpvhuos7ZiIsIiIsIjUiXQ==) for 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 25 bytes * 0.5 = 12.5

```
{$_,|flat (1..$_-1)X..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiVepyYtJ7FEQcNQT08lXtdQMwJE1/4vTqxUUFKJV7C1U6hOUwCKKCmk5RcpAFWZ/QcA)

This generates the list consisting of the input number n, and the flattened list of ranges 1 .. (n-1), 2 .. (n-1), ..., n-2 .. n-1, n-1 .. n-1.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
,/{x#x}'1+!:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LRr65QrqhVN9RWtOLiSos2jQUAOr0FTA==)

Short and sweet.

Explanations:

```
,/{x#x}'1+!:  Main function. Takes implicit input x via Right (:)
          !   Create a range between 0 to x (exclusive)
        1+    + 1 to each of them
       '      For each of the numbers in the range
  {   }       Execute a function that
     x        Takes the number as implicit argument x
   x#         And duplicate by themselves' amount of times
,/            Join together
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 57 * 0.5 = 28.5

This entry is a subroutine named "l" (for "list"?)

```
sub l{$d=$n=shift;while($d){for($d--..$n){@a=(@a,$_)}}@a}
```

You can test it like this:

```
$"=", ";
@a=l(3);
print "[@a]\n"; # prints "[3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]"
@a=();          # needed because the function does not re-initialize @a
@a=l(5);
print "[@a]\n"; # prints "[5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
```

A prior solution is shorter (45 characters), but doesn't print the output prettily so it was disqualified

```
$d=$n=<>;while($d){for($d--..$n){print"$_ "}}
```

For an input of 3, this one prints (with a trailing space):

```
3 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: On second thought, only the `[]` are required. You can get rid of the `,`

Answer (score 0):

## [JAGL](http://github.com/globby/jagl) Alpha 1.1 - 15 bytes

```
1Ti[r{d()+S*}/E
```

Explanation:

```
1Ti               Push 1, take input, and convert to integer
   [r             Increment and make a range
     {d()+S*}     Push a block that makes an array with x occurrences of x
             /E   Map over list and flatten
```

Comment: I can see this is your own language, mere two hours older than the question. I guess this is just a test of the language? Note you won't be able to use v 1.2 for this challenge, and it wouldn't be a good test of your language anyways. Oh, and the documentation needs to be vastly improved before a public release ;-)

Comment: I'll work on that. I haven't had much time to make the full documentation yet, but that will be the next step.

The language itself is a few days old, but the most recent update was released just a couple hours before the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 48 * 0.5 = 24

```
$i=<>;$"=", ";@a=map{-$_..$i}-$i..-1;print"[@a]"
```

Test run:

```
$ ./repeated.pl <<< 5
[5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Are you sure about `<!-- language=lang-perl -->`? The result doesn't seem right.

Comment: I know. `$"` makes the syntax highlight crazy :)

Comment: Can you rename the variable? Switch to lang-none?

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 56 Bytes * 0.5 = 28

```
f(I)->L=lists,L:flatten([L:seq(X,I)||X<-L:seq(I,1,-1)]).
```

Using a list comprehension, reverses the list using `lists:seq(UpperBound, 1, -1)` and for each element, creates a sequence using `lists:seq(CurrentValue, UpperBound)`. The eventual list is then flattened.

Expanded:

```
f(I) ->
    lists:flatten([lists:seq(X, I) || X <- lists:seq(I, 1, -1)]).
```

Input: `module_name:f(9).`

Output: `[9,8,9,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5: 30 bytes / 2 = 15

Added one byte for the `-p` flag.

```
#!perl -p
$_=join$",map-$_..$',-$_..-//
```

Takes parameter on the input:

```
$ perl int.pl <<<5
5 4 5 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java (adjacent equals ok): 276 bytes

```
public class a{public static int[]b(final int c){final int d=(c+1)*c/2;final int[]e=new int[d];int f=1;int g=0;for(int i=0;i<d;i++){if(g==f){f++;g=0;;}
e[i]=f;g++;}
return e;}
public static void main(String[]args){final int q=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();b(q);}}
```

### Java (adjacent equals not ok): 442 * 0.5 = 221 bytes

```
public class a{private static int h=1;public static int[]j(final int k){final int[]l=new int[k+1];for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){l[i]=i;}
final int m=(k+1)*k/2;final int[]n=new int[m];for(int i=1;i<n.length;i++){n[i]=o(l,k);}
n[0]=k;return n;}
private static int o(final int[]p,final int q){if(h>q){h=1;}
while(p[h]==0){h++;}
p[h]=p[h]-1;return h++;}
public static void main(String[]args){final int q=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();j(q);}}
```

Comment: OK then I removed the aim statement, submission now aligns with the criteria.

Comment: minified to comply with rules.

Comment: Most of the modifiers on your variables aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

### CoffeeScript, 57

```
f=(n)->i=0;a=[];(j=0;a.push i while(j++<i))while(i++<n);a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 44 * 0.5 = 22

```
function r=f(n);r=[];for i=1:n;r=[i:n,r];end
```

> f(4) == [4     3     4     2     3     4     1     2     3     4]

## Javascript, 63 * 0.5 = 31.5

```
F=n=>{r=[m=n];while(--n){r=r.slice(0,m-n).concat(n,r)}return r}
```

> F(4) == [ 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4 ]

Nothing fancy, just concatenating arrays.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 36 bytes

```
time {time {puts $i} [incr i]} $argv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaEaQhaUlhQrqGTWKkRn5iUXKWTG1iqoJBall/3//98UAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes * 0.5 = 2

```
R|]r
```

[Run and debug it online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=R%7C]r&i=1%0A%0A2%0A%0A3%0A%0A4%0A%0A5%0A%0A6%0A%0A7%0A%0A8%0A%0A9%0A%0A10%0A%0A72&a=1&m=1) Note: To verify that is does indeed work, you'll need to step through the execution, as the values are printed as characters rather than numbers.

#### Explanation:

```
R|]r
R       Range [1..n].     Example: [1, 2, 3, 4]
 |]     List of suffixes: Example: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]
   r    Reverse.          Example: [[4], [3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
        Implicit flatten and print (treating numbers as characters and concatenating).
```

#### Without the bonus (3 bytes):

```
R|]
```

or

```
R|[     (This does what you expect)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 109 bytes (score: 54.5 bytes)

```java
import java.util.*;
```

```java
n->{List l=new Stack();l.add(n);for(int i=0,j;i<n-1;i++)for(j=i;j++<n;)l.add(j);return l;}
```

That's a lambda from `int` to `List<Object>`. The members are, of course, `Integer`s.

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XY9Ba4QwEIXP@ityTOoa2ksvUaGXQqGlB4@lh6xGmRgnIY5blsXfbpV6WHqa4XtvmPesvujcB4O2HVYYg4/E7MbkTODkg0rTMJ8dNKxxeprYhwZktzQ54ESattEBand31s3YEHiUr8dSvCGZ3sTTnekdJio@z9Y0VFVs1IN5iZGVK@bVbdeYK9H8sJp0M3ChnNRty1GozkcOSAzKx5NVUGD@pCDLxM5tCcpmWYFK/PmtUNHQHJE5tazJVudf9IuHdnsOyGuKgP3XN9Oxn8ReMqmvE5lR@plk2ERyyI@cUofgrvxZCJUmS7qsvw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes * 0.5 = 3

```
s>RSQS
```

[Try it here!](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=s%3ERSQS&input=5&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## Golang, 80 bytes

```
func n(a int)(r[]int){for i:=0;i<=a;i++{for j:=0;j<i;j++{r=append(r,i)}};return}
```

Ungolfed and readable:

```
func n(a int) (r []int){
    for i := 0; i <= a; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < i; j++ {
            r = append(r, i)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBDsIgEIXhtZyCdAWpMXUr5Q7ujYtJhWbQDmRCVw1nR8rqJd/711gTLF9YndwASQjcUuQsB7/lQQi/09IPpeUhLg1vT0bKP1Kk7pPWotTekALZXCt@vc89fGSJDzsZnC0YHMcu4ZQwowkN2EJKjj6Kr6hLMezyzlRq/QM)

Pretty straightforward solution and probably pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 17 bytes x 0.5 = 8.5

```
FbQ=+Y-SQSb)+eYPY
```

Possibly golfable. Explanation:

```
FbQ=+Y-SQSb)+eYPY
FbQ                For b in range(int(input()))
     Y             A variable containing an empty list
   =+              +=
      -            The set difference of
       SQ          [1, 2, ..., input()]
         Sb        [1, 2, ..., b]
           )       End function
            +eY    Append to the last element of Y
               PY  All but the last element of Y
```

So for example, putting `3` through the loop would yield `[1,2,3,2,3,3]`, then the last five characters will transpose that final `3` to the beginning so no two numbers touch each other.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 14 bytes

```
~),1>{.[()]*}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05Tx9CuWi9aQzNWq1b1/39TAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 9 bytes

```
L,Rdz£XbF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJyil6tDiiCS3/yo5iblJKYkKhnb2XP7//5sCAA)

In most other languages, it might be worth going for the bonus by using things like prefixes etc. Not in add++.

### Explained

```
L,Rdz£XbF
L,        # create a lambda that:
  R       # pushes the range [1...n] to the stack
   dz     # ... zips that with itself
     £X   # ... reduces each item by item repetition
       bF # ... and flattens that
```

Answer (score 0):

## [brainf***](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 98 bytes

```
[[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<-[[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<-<[-]<[->+>>+<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<]<[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFBTsMwELznFXOjVQiHQiUOkU9I/QAShyiHbbJtrDp2tHZa4PPFDkHQCgnhk@UZz@7MbIW03Y3N4fzEjXDPNmCnxQc0bAyCg2c5MsiD0JMcWHDq2OLEGERHtg5wY4ChwHKLkDDDIV1ATRjJRJ7bC/WQ0cLZCZlHGCaZBmUFVJZtdJyk7RDl4uAfayxCpz34lfrBcNQwbzg5OXiMQ2JabRntyOme1Fu9j1tN62m7X2b51zlXVaFylZdlrVRVlGWuVF0Wv7@WVVGXE5KghE1gQiM8Q9ef6vPGYUvN4crBSYcORzJxydV6nQwlH5xiHD23F/nqz4w6ppYly6N4XhfZS6ej9yQWqcL2JuCdxd2C2hYPj7P3HovG2SNLrFFcj9RQRMg3WsPHNMwczxJk27nCVFr2nJrzU3P03f79CguCH6jhyx8UMoUq/@e5i5n@yVH1@QM)

Takes input as first cell on tape and outputs onto the tape. I'm not sure if this is allowed but input and output is really painful in brainf*** so I'm presuming it's allowed. The example on TIO has header and footer code to print the values out because I couldn't find a way to dump the memory into the output.

If you consider that each brainf*** character only contains 3 bits of information (as there are only 8 possible characters), then it's only `98 * (3/8) = 36.75` bytes of information.

I would put an explanation but I wrote the code yesterday and have forgotten how it works since then.

Answer (score 0):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org), <s>44</s> 33 bytes * 0.5 bonus = <s>22</s> 16.5

```
n=4
l=Flatten(Zip(1…a,a,n…1))
```

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/erebyygv)

My first time code golfing with GeoGebra :D and I gotta say, GeoGebra has a ton more built-in functions than Desmos. I think I'll start trying out GeoGebra a little bit more, it definitely has a lot of features. It's also surprisingly golfy, especially when it comes to lists!

But, I couldn't figure out how to get functions working properly in GeoGebra for some reason, so the input has to be changed by editing the value of `n`, and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The code currently has a default input of `n=4`.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), score: 2 (4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) \$\times \frac{1}{2}\$ bonus)

```
╒╒x─
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1ElAVPFoSsP//4ZcRlzGXCZcplxmAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒     # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ╒    # Map each value to an inner list in the range [1, value]
  x   # Reverse this list of lists
   ─  # Flatten
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## APOL, 14 bytes

`⭳(Ƒ(⧣ Ƒ(∈ ⋒)))`

Explanation:

```
         Implicit print
⭳(       Flatten list
  Ƒ(     One-indexed list-builder for loop
    ⧣    Integer input
    Ƒ(   One-indexed list-builder for loop
      ∈  Loop item (of parent loop in this case)
      ⋒  For iterator (what's being iterated through)
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) * 0.5 = 2.5

```
õõU c
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9fVVIGM&input=NQ)

```
õõU c #
õ     # For all numbers X in the range [1, input]:
 õU   #  Generate the range [input, X]
    c # Flatten
```

A cheatier [3 byte](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9fVV&input=NQ) version produces the same visible output, but that's only because Japt's default string representation of 2D arrays isn't very clear. Using the `-Q` flag reveals the [real output](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVE&code=9fVV&input=NQ).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes * 0.5 = 17

```ruby
->n{(1..n).flat_map{[*n-_1+1..n]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3lXTt8qo1DPX08jT10nISS-JzEwuqo7XydOMNtUGisbW1EJXLChTcok1jIZwFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md) * 0.5 = 1.5

```
RȷI
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhZLgk5s91xSnJRcDBVYsNAUwgAA)

##### Explanation

```python
RȷI  # Implicit input          ->  5 
R    # Range [1..input]        ->  [1,2,3,4,5]
 ȷ   # Map over each:
  I  #  Range [input..n]       ->  [[5,4,3,2,1],[5,4,3,2],[5,4,3],[5,4],[5]]
     # Sum (flatten) the list  ->  [5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,5,4,3,5,4,5]
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jot 23 | awk NF=OFS=\$_
```

---

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
10101010101010101010
1111111111111111111111
121212121212121212121212
13131313131313131313131313
1414141414141414141414141414
151515151515151515151515151515
16161616161616161616161616161616
1717171717171717171717171717171717
181818181818181818181818181818181818
19191919191919191919191919191919191919
2020202020202020202020202020202020202020
212121212121212121212121212121212121212121
22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
2323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323
```