# The negative order integer challenge, but it's Prime Time!

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

*Im talking about [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103670/output-integers-in-negative-order-increase-the-maximum-integer-everytime), take a look at it if you are a bit confused.*

## Main Task

Your task is to output concatenated integers, in decreasing order, but increasing the maximum integer everytime you hit `1` *(for this question, 1 will be considered a prime number)*. While this doesn't sound any different from the first question, here comes the tricky part: All outputted numbers **may only be primes**. These will be strung together into a single string without spaces or newlines. Your input will also be a **prime number**.

Example:

```
1
21
321
5321
75321
1175321
Valid output:
1213215321753211175321
```

### Input

Your code may only take one input: the highest prime to be printed. This input can come from anywhere (graphical, STDIN). You are **assured** that the input is a prime number.

### Output

You will have to output the resulting number. You can get this number by keep counting down, only count the number if it's a prime, then connect all results together to one number. The last number "row" (e.g. `7, 5, 3, 2, 1`) has to be printed fully. The output could be anything (numbers, strings, graphical), as long as it's readable. The same Regex pattern for checking your test cases applies:

```
^(\D*(\d)+\D*|)$
```

If your output doesn't match with this pattern, your code is invalid.

### Rules

- The input is assured to be prime, do not include error handling, unless you want/need to.
- The output may only be a full-connected number, therefore not split up by anything, not even newlines.
- Your algorithm shouldn't check for the first instance of `N` appearing (for instance, the `17` in `1175321`), but rather for the first instance of `N` as the actual number.
- Your input is assured to be positive, do not add handling unless you want/need to.

### Test cases

```
Input: -2, 0
Output: Any, or none (number isn't positive)

Input: 9
Output: Any, or none (number isn't prime)

Input: 1
Output: 1

Input: 7
Output: 121321532175321

Input: 23
Output: 1213215321753211175321131175321171311753211917131175321231917131175321
```

## Winner

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the author of the code with the least length in bytes wins!

Comment: I thought that for input `7` the output would be `121321532175321` instead

Comment: I think I fixed them now. @KritixiLithos

Comment: I won't suggest changing the challenge, but I don't think `1` is a prime by definition.

Comment: Yes, 1 is not a prime, but I added it for the sake of the challenge, I guess ;) @ErikGolferエリックゴルファー

Comment: 1. Having a test case `1` directly contradicts the spec, which "***assures***" that the input number will be a prime. 2. The output spec seems to contain multiple contradictions and ambiguities. "*The last number "row" (e.g. 7, 5, 3, 2, 1) has to be printed fully*" - so the others don't? "*The same Regex pattern for checking your test cases applies*", but "*The output may only be a full-connected number, therefore not split up by anything*" contradicts that regex. But the regex is clearly dodgy anyway because it allows the empty string, and there's no input which could give that.

Comment: @PeterTaylor For your first statement, I have specified in the question that *(for this question, 1 will be considered a prime number)*. The other rows obviously have to be printed fully, as explained in the task and test cases. The regex allows for a fully connected number, with anything before and after, because people had problems with printing arrays or other specific characters (e.g. `[121321]\n`)

Comment: 1. "*A single trailing newline is allowed.*" is redundant/inconsistent with the regex pattern that allows **any** number of trailing characters. 2. The intro sentence "*Your task is to output integers*" is misleading since you later ask to output a single number. 3. The whole explanation of the sequence and the output is confusing - people basically have to reverse-engineer what you mean by studying the examples (sequence listing and test cases). The last challenge also had these issues, and I addressed them there in a suggested edit there, which you rejected... :(

Comment: What's the point in arbitrarily making 1 a prime?

Comment: `The input is assured to be prime, do not include error handling, unless you want/need to.` Adding unnecessary error handling would make an answer [not a serious contender](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10836/20283), so this might be better worded as just `The input is assured to be prime.`

Comment: The negative order integer challenge but every time it's a prime it gets faster ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ÆR1;;\UFV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4LcjQ2jom1C3s////RsYA)

#### How it works

```
ÆR1;;\UFV  Main link. Argument: n

ÆR         Prime range; yield all primes up to n.
  1;       Prepend the "prime" 1.
    ;\     Cumulative concatenation; yield all prefixes of the prime range.
      U    Upend; reverse each prefix.
       F   Flatten the resulting 2D array.
        V  Eval. This casts the integer array to string first, thus concatenating
           the integers.
```

Comment: I know I'm too deep into learning about golfing when I read the Jelly to understand the question rather than the other way round. (This is actually a pretty readable Jelly program, as they go; the only confusing point for me was the weird special case of `V` on a list.)

Answer (score 5):

## Processing, 161 bytes

```
int p(int n){for(int k=1;++k<=sqrt(n);)if(n%k<1)return 0;return 1;}void t(int n){for(int i=1,j;i<=n;i++){if(p(i)<1)continue;for(j=i;j>0;j--)print(p(j)<1?"":j);}}
```

One function does the primality checking, the other does the printing. Call it by `t(7)`

#### Ungolfed

The first function does the primality checking. It returns an `int` instead of a `boolean` since this way more bytes are saved. (`int` instead of `boolean`, `0` instead of `false`, `1` instead of `true`)

```
int Q103891p(int n){
  for(int k=1;++k<=sqrt(n);)
    if(n%k<1)return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

The second function prints out the string. It iterates through every number, if it is not a prime, skip to the next iteration. If it is a prime, it continues down to the printing inside another `for`-loop. Again, if the number is prime, then we print it, otherwise not.

```
void Q103891(int n){
  for(int i=1,j;i<=n;i++){
    if(p(i)<1)continue;
    for(j=i;j>0;j--)
      print(p(j)<1?"":j);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ÆR;@1
ÇÇ€UVV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4LcjawZDrcPvh9kdNa0LDwv7//29kDAA)

If it hadn't been for `1`s at all, my code would have just been `ÆRÆRUVV` for 7 bytes.

Enhanced explanation:

```
ÇÇ€UVV Main link. Arguments: z.
Ç      Run link1 on z.
 Ç€    Run link1 on z's elements.
   U   Reverse z's elements.
    V  Flatten z.
     V Concatenate z's elements.

ÆR;@1 Link 1. Arguments: z.
ÆR    Range of primes [2..z].
    1 Integer: 1.
  ;@  Concatenate x to y.
```

The Irish guy (called Dennis?) somehow [outgolfed](/a/103940/41024) me lol.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
LDpÏX¸ì€Lí˜ÐXQsp+ÏJ
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TERww49YwrjDrOKCrEzDrcucw5BYUXNwK8OPSg&input=Nw)

**Explanation**

```
L                     # range [1 ... input]
 DpÏ                  # keep only primes
    X¸ì               # prepend a 1
       €L             # map: range [1 ... n]
         í            # reverse each sublist
          ˜           # flatten list to 1D
           Ð          # triplicate
            XQ        # check elements in one copy for equality with 1
              sp      # check elements in one copy for primality
                +     # add the above lists giving a list with true values at indices
                      # comtaining 1 or a prime
                 Ï    # keep only those elements of the unmodified copy of the list
                  J   # join
```

Comment: Amazed by the `DpÏ` statement. Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
y:{e1|e#p}f@[rcw\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@19pVZ1qWJOqXFCb5hBdlFwe8/@/OQA)

Can't seem to get shorter than that...

#### Explanation

```
y                      The list [0, ..., Input]
 :{      }f            Find all...
   e1                     ...elements that are 1 (there is 1)...
     |                    ...or...
      e#p                 ...elements that are prime...
           @[          Take a prefix of the result
             rc        Reverse it and concatenate it into a number
               w       Write to STDOUT
                  \    Backtrack: try another prefix
```

Answer (score 2):

## GameMaker Language, 169 bytes

Main function (68 bytes)

```
b=""for(i=1;i<=argument0;i++){c=i while(j)b+=string(p(c--))}return b
```

Function p (46 bytes)

```
for(a=0;a<argument0;a++)while q(++b){}return b
```

Function q (55 bytes)

```
n=argument0 for(i=2;i<n;i++)if!(n mod i)p=1return p|n=1
```

Comment: Nice, someone who uses GML

Comment: @FireCubez Thanks:) I used to use it a lot. It was actually the first programming language I learned.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
Zq"1@ZqP]1v!VXz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x9VqGToEFUYEGuolhEWUfX/v5ExAA)

```
Zq      % Implicit input. Push array of primes up to that value
"       % For each prime in that array
  1     %   Push 1
  @     %   Push current prime
  Zq    %   Push array of primes up to that
  P     %   Reverse
]       % End
1       % Push 1
&h      % Concatenate all stack horizontally
V       % Convert to string
Xz      % Remove spaces. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 41 bytes

```
{[~] flat [\R,] 1,|grep *.is-prime,2..$_}
```

([Try it online.](https://tio.run/#ttqTH))

#### Explanation:

- `1, |grep(*.is-prime, 2..$_)`: Sequence of 1 and primes... `(1 2 3 5)`
- `[,] ...`: Reduce ("fold") over comma operator... `(1 2 3 5)`
- `[\,] ...`: With intermediate results ([triangular reduce](http://perl6maven.com/tutorial/perl6-reduction-triangle))... `((1) (1 2) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 5))`
- `[\R,] ...`: Apply [reversing](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Reversed_Operators) meta-operator to the comma... `((1) (2 1) (3 2 1) (5 3 2 1))`
- `[~] flat ...`: Remove list nesting, and fold over string concat operator... `1213215321`

(This is based on [my answer for the previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103701/14880).)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
ToString/@(1<>Prime@Range[Range@PrimePi@#,0,-1]/.Prime@0->1)&
```

Unnamed function taking an integer argument and returning a string. (If the input is not a prime, it just "rounds it down" to the nearest prime; if the input is nonpositive, it pretends it's 1.)

This implementation uses the nasty trick from [Martin Ender's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103706/56178) to the similar previous challenge (who says this old dog can't learn new tricks?): abusing `<>` to flatten a nested list of integers.

The nested list in question starts by generating a similar nested list as in that answer, with the appropriate length (given by `PrimePi@#`, the number of primes up to and including the input); then `Prime` is applied to every element. For example, for the input `5` which is the 3rd prime, the code `Range[Range@PrimePi@#,0,-1]` yields `{{1,0},{2,1,0},{3,2,1,0}}`, and applying `Prime` to each element yields `{{2,Prime[0]},{3,2,Prime[0]},{5,3,2,Prime[0]}}` since the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd primes are 2, 3, and 5, respectively. I feel proud that I managed to add even more errors to Martin Ender's approach—Mathematica complains every time it writes `Prime[0]`.

`Prime[0]` isn't a thing, but that's okay: `/.Prime@0->1` turns them all into `1`s. And we also want a `1` on the front, so we replace the `""` from Martin Ender's answer with simply `1`, which actually saves a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 72 bytes

```php
for(;$n<$argv[1];print$s=$n.$s)for($i=2;$i>1;)for($i=++$n;--$i&&$n%$i;);
```

Run wit `-r`

**breakdown**

```php
for(;$n<$argv[1];               // loop $n up to argument:
    print$s=$n.$s)                  // 2. prepend $n to $s, print $s
    for($i=2;$i>1;)                 // 1. find next prime: break if $i<2
        for($i=++$n;--$i&&$n%$i;);      // if $n is prime, $i is 1 after loop (0 for $n=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 12 bytes

```
jkf!tPTs}R1S
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jkf%21tPTs%7DR1S&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=9%0A1%0A7%0A23&debug=0).