# Reversed Iota's

Tags: code-golf

I [didn't](https://github.zhaw.ch/munt/Gulf) invent this challenge, but I find it very interesting to solve.

For **every** input number, e.g.:

```
4
```

Generate a range from 1 to that number:

```
[1 2 3 4]
```

And then, for every item in that list, generate a list from 1 to that number:

```
[[1] [1 2] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4]]
```

Then, reverse every item of that list.

```
[[1] [2 1] [3 2 1] [4 3 2 1]]
```

### Notes:

- 1 being a loose item is allowed, since flattening will not matter with this anyway.
- To preserve the spirit of the challenge, the range has to be 1-indexed.
- You may flatten the list if your platform doesn't support the concept of nested lists.

Comment: what just happened to the original poster??

Comment: @RGS Anonymization.

Comment: may we output as a sequence of numbers (`1 2 1 3 2 1 4 3 2 1`), say, if a platform doesn't have a concept of multi-dimensional array/list?

Comment: @S.S.Anne in what sense? And what would be a plausible reason?

Comment: @RGS The user has been disassociated from the question for some reason, probably because they didn't want to take credit for it. It's not been made Community Wiki so the answerers will still get reputation. Or, maybe the user deleted their account right after they posted this (since copying the number into /users/ doesn't work).

Comment: It should be noted that the challenge says “for _every_ input”, implying multiple inputs are possible, but most answers only handle a single input...

Comment: @Dúthomhas I assume they meant "for **any** (numeric) input"?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Hence the reason I observed it, because “for every” and “for any” mean two totally different things.

Comment: @Dúthomhas for the native english speaker yes. But a foreigner may easily use the two interchangeably. Since the question doesn't mention anything about multiple inputs/outputs, how to format them or if the program asks for them all at once or one at a time, the simplest interpretation is probably consensus.

Answer (score 11):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
,⍨\⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@dR74qYR72b/6c9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/P4P9A2ivY308hTcEEAA)

`,⍨\` cumulative reverse-concatenation reduction of

`⍳` the iota

Comment: "1 being a loose item is allowed" if I understand this, this allows for a 4-byter

Comment: @KritixiLithos Ah, that's what it means. Nice.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```r
Map(`:`,1:scan(),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3zexQCPBKkHH0Ko4OTFPQ1PHUPO/6X8A)

`Map(f,...)` applies `f` elementwise to each member of `...`, recycling as needed, resulting in a `list`, so we just supply `1` as the `to` argument to `:` to get the reversed.

-3 bytes thanks to [Vlo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30693/vlo)!

Comment: `Map()` 19b, https://tio.run/##K/r/3zexQCPBKkHH0Ko4OTFPQ1PHUPO/6X8A

Comment: @Vlo I don't know why I didn't think of that; `Map` is pretty much always shorter than `lapply`, and more flexible too...Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## Jelly, 3 bytes

```
RRU
```

```
R     Range from 1 to input
 R    (implicitly) map over said range and create a range from 1 to this element
  U   reverse each of those
```

You can [try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8oKPT///8mAA)

Courtesy of @JonathanAllan, we also have two other 3-"byters"

```
RrL
RrE
```

I think it is not often that golfing languages solve a challenge with only `a-zA-Z` characters

Comment: Reminds me of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133116, a Pyth answer consisting only of `S` and `s`.

Comment: A couple more 3 byte `a-zA-Z` only solutions are `RrL` and `RrE`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I don't think I understand the `RrE` one :/

Answer (score 7):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), 29

```bash
eval eval echo \\{{1..$1}..1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UsMUcBQiRn5CvExFRXG@rpqRjW6ukZ1v7//98EAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
LLí
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx@fw2v//TQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
Range[Range@#,1,-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PygxLz01Gkw6KOsY6ugaxqr9DyjKzCtRcEiPNon9/x8A)

-3 bytes from @att

Comment: `Range` is `Listable`, so you can save one byte: `Reverse/@Range@Range@#&`.

Comment: `#-Range@#+1&~Array~#&` for 21

Comment: ...and `Range[Range@#,1,-1]&` for 20

Answer (score 5):

## [shell + sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 15 bytes

```bash
seq $1|sed G\;h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEHFsKY4NUXBPcYaKPDfBAA)

Outputs like so, `1\n\n2\n1\n\n3\n2\n1\n\n[...]`

`seq $1` creates a sequence from 1 to the first argument `$1`

`|sed ...` which is piped into a sed script

sed works on a line-by-line basis; it first reads the first line into the buffer, called the "pattern space", after which the program commands is run on it. At the end of the program's execution on the first line, the remaining pattern space is implicitly printed. Then sed reads the next line into the pattern space, replacing the previous contents, and runs the commands on it, repeating for all lines of input (unless a command specifies otherwise).

The pattern space is not saved between lines, but what is is the hold space. The hold space is another buffer, that starts empty, and can be modified by program commands. Its contents are carried on to the execution of the next line of input.

The `G` command appends a newline followed by the content of the hold space to that of the pattern space. Then the `h` command replaces the hold space with the content of the pattern space. This effectively reverses the lines of input encountered so far, writing them to the pattern space – implicitly printing at the end of processing the current line – and saving them to the hold space so that upon reading subsequent lines of input, the new reversed "list" can be constructed with `G;h`.

The `;` is escaped in the program as `\;` because otherwise the shell interprets it as terminating a shell command.

Answer (score 5):

## [<s>Perl 6</s> Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>24 15 13</s> 10 bytes

-2 removed parenthesis

-3 thanks to nwellnhof

```perl6
^*+1 X…1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPs/TkvbUCHiUcMyw//WXMWJlQppCib/AQ)

### Explanation

```perl6
^*+1     # make a range from 1 .. argument (whatever star).
     X…1 # create ranges descending to 1 using cross product metaoperator.
```

### Previous version, 24 bytes

```perl6
(^<<(^*+1)X+1)>>.reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfI87GRiNOS9tQMwKI7ez0ilLLUouKU/9bc3EVJ1YqpCmY/AcA)

#### Explanation

```perl6
     ^*+1                # make a range from 1 .. argument (whatever star)
 ^<<(    )               # replace each element with a range from 0 .. element - 1
                         # (via hyper prefix operator)
          X+1            # shift the range to 1 .. element
                         # (via cross product metaoperator)
(            )>>.reverse # reverse each list (via hyper method operator)
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPs/TkvbUCHiUcMyw//WXMWJlQppCib/AQ). I have no idea why `X...` doesn't work.

Comment: @nwellnhof Very interesting. I think I tried `X...`, but not this. I remember getting the same results. I definitely use `X` much more frequently than a pair of `>>`

Comment: Some update has made the unicode operator act the same as the ascii equivalent, breaking this elegant answer

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
|',\1+!:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqkZdJ8ZQW9Hqf5qCyX8A)

-2 thanks to ngn :-)

Comment: Another 8-byter is [`-!'-1-!:`](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9JVVNc11FW04uJKUzABABfdAso=)

Comment: @coltim neat :-)

Comment: Based on coltims suggestion, `-!'|!-:` works for 7

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>50</s>  49 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```javascript
f=n=>n?[...f(n-1),(g=_=>n?[n,...g(--n)]:[])()]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchRCoAgDADQ62zQBkFfgXUQkRBTKWRGRtdf4deDd/rXt3Af10NS96iajJhFVsvMCYRGHCCbrZcMf2YgEnSzdQgdDVVaLZFLzZBgQtQP)

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##HchRCoAgDADQ62zQBkFfgXUQkRBTKWRGRtdf4deDd/rXt3Af10NS96iajJhFVsvMCYRGHCCbrZcMf2YgEnSzdQgdDVVaLZFLzZBgQtQP)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 54 bytes

```php
function($x){for(;$y<$x;$a[]=range(++$y,1));return$a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc0xCsIwFAbgPafI8A8JtYPg9hrcvEQpEmLS6PBeSFtoEa9uxO8CX8mlDdeSi0JyLW0c1qewwW7fSaohHAN2gh8nVz3P0XQdjtPZWqpx3SrD06eRgminkYyGrzNrSyqGLPq1CN8jB3lEA7HULl8p/2Bp/e0H)

Or recursive:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 54 bytes

```php
function f($x){return$x?f($x-1)+[$x=>range($x,1)]:[];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUKjSri1JLSovyVCrsQVxdQ03taJUKW7uixLz0VKCAjqFmrFV0rHXt/9TkjHyFrOL8vPjUvOT8lFQNoH4FlcSi9DwFTQVN6/8m//ILQMYW/9d1AwA)

Or with PHP-formatted printed output:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 38 bytes

```php
for(;$x<$argn;print_r(range(++$x,1)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVKmxUEovS86wLijLzSuKLNIoS89JTNbS1VSp0DDU1Na3//zf5l19QkpmfV/xf1w0A)

Answer (score 4):

## x86-16 machine code, 12 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: 33c0 4050 ab48 75fc 58e2 f7c3         3.@P.Hu.X...
```

Unassembled listing:

```
33 C0       XOR  AX, AX         ; AX = 0
        OUT_LOOP:
40          INC  AX             ; start at 1
50          PUSH AX             ; save starting position
        IN_LOOP:
AB          STOSW               ; write to output buffer, increment DI
48          DEC  AX             ; AX--
75 FC       JNZ  IN_LOOP        ; if AX > 0, keep looping
58          POP  AX             ; restore starting position
E2 F7       LOOP OUT_LOOP 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Input Number in `CX`, output array of `WORD`, at `[DI]`.

Example I/O using DOS test driver program:

[image]

Comment: What do you run DOS on?

Comment: @S.S.Anne this example I just ran in [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) because I was lazy. Typically I'll use [PCE](http://www.hampa.ch/pce/pce-ibmpc.html) to test since it's an actual IBM PC 5150 "bare metal" emulation.

Comment: Ah, DOSBox. Now that I look at it more closely it does look like DOSBox.

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 13 bytes

```perl6
{[\R,] 1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzo6JkgnVsFQT08lvvZ/cWKlQpqCyX8A)

Cumulative reverse with the range 1 to input.

Comment: One of the great things about Raku is that there are at least [two equally short ways to do it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199340/91521).

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 10 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```
(⌽1+↕)¨1+↕
```

[Try it online!](https://bqnpad.mechanize.systems/s?bqn=eyJkb2MiOiJcblxuIyBGb3IgZXZlcnkgaW5wdXQgbnVtYmVyLCBnZW5lcmF0ZSBhIHJhbmdlIGZyb20gMSB0byB0aGF0IG51bWJlci5cbiMgRm9yIGV2ZXJ5IGl0ZW0gaW4gdGhhdCBsaXN0LCBnZW5lcmF0ZSBhIGxpc3QgZnJvbSAxIHRvIHRoYXQgbnVtYmVyLlxuIyBSZXZlcnNlIGV2ZXJ5IGl0ZW0gb2YgdGhhdCBsaXN0LlxubiDihpAgNVxuU29sMCDihpAgKOKMvTEr4oaVKcKoMSvihpVcblNvbDEg4oaQICgxK%2BKGlSl7KOKMvfCdlL0pwqjwnZS9fVxuU29sMiDihpAgKOKMveKGlSnCqOKGlVxuXG5Tb2wwIG5cblxuIiwicHJldlNlc3Npb25zIjpbXSwiY3VycmVudFNlc3Npb24iOnsiY2VsbHMiOltdLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOjE2NzUwMDU4NzEzMzV9LCJjdXJyZW50Q2VsbCI6eyJmcm9tIjowLCJ0byI6MjQzLCJyZXN1bHQiOm51bGx9fQ%3D%3D)

#### Explanation

```
(⌽1+↕)¨1+↕
       1+↕    1.  Get list of integers from 1 to n.
      ¨       2a. For each integer i in the list...
( 1+↕)        2b. get a list of integers from 1 to i...
(⌽   )        2c. and then reverse that list.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 19 bytes

```powershell
1.."$args"|%{$_..1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPT0klsSi9WKlGtVolXk/PsPb///8mAA)

Generates the range from `1` to input `$args`, then constructs the reversed range for each of those numbers. Tack on a [`-join`](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPT0klsSi9WKlGtVolXk/PUDcrPzNPXUe99v///yYA) to better see how the arrays are created (because PowerShell inserts a newline between each element, it's tough to see the individual arrays).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda n:[[*range(i+1,0,-1)]for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpaqygxLz1VI1PbUMdAR9dQMzYtv0ghUyEzTwEikacZ@7@gKDOvRCNNw0RT8z8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 12 (13) bytes

```
,{)),(;-1%}%`
```

```
,{)),(;-1%}%` #Reversed iota of iota
,             #0 to n-1 iota
 {        }%  #For each element in the iota
 {))      }   #Increment by 2
 {  ,     }   #Iota
 {   (;   }   #Pop leading 0
 {     -1%}   #Reverse it
            ` #Pretty output, not needed if you use a better stack-interpreter
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv8V@nWlNTR8Na11C1VjXh/38A)

Below is my old solution, I gained inspiration after posting and improved it.

```
),(;{),(;-1%}%`
```

Comma is the function that builds an array 0 to n-1, "iota expand".

```
),(;{),(;-1%}%` #Take in a number, output reversed expanded iota
)               #Increment input by 1
 ,              #Iota expand
  (;            #Remove leading 0
    {       }%  #For every element, do the following
    {)      }   #Increment by 1
    { ,     }   #Iota expand
    {  (;   }   #Remove leading 0
    {    -1%}   #Reverse
              ` #Pretty output; technically not needed
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv8V9TR8O6GkToGqrWqib8/w8A)

Comment: It feels like you are from the previous decade - you are wielding GolfScript so well!

Comment: I had a week off and wanted to learn an esolang for codegolf - osabie was a bit too over-the-top, APL had too much to remember, but Golfscript was easy for me to understand right away - so I spent an entire week just doubling down learning the ins and outs, and now I can visualize the stack and understand exactly what I'm doing as I'm doing it, it's a very elegant language.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```ruby
->n,*a{(1..n).map{|x|a=[x]+a}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PRyuxWsNQTy9PUy83saC6pqIm0Ta6IlY7sbb2f4FCWrRJ7H8A)

Thanks Value Ink (as usual) for -4 bytes.

Comment: `->n,*a{(1..n).map{|x|a=[x]+a}}` is 30 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 45 bytes

```
: f ( n -- s ) [1,b] [ 1 [a,b] >array ] map ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcwxC8IwEIbhvb/iGxVMoYNLCq7SpYPiFDqc9aodTOPdKfTXx@j2DC/vRKMtki/nrj96kAitiifZoxaKd1Yov94cx6IkbLYmmaOhrbre48QfFuWbmxejKntM2CDCOSi2CM3uOiCgQaCfDv87hrJPaPO@1HX@Ag)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```
f n=scanl(flip(:))[1][2..n]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 22 bytes

```sh
eval echo {{1..$1}..1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxP7UsMUchNTkjX6G62lBPT8WwVk/PsPa/JhdXmoIhEBsBsTEQm4Bog/8A)

`{{1..$1}..1}` -> `{1..1} {2..1} {3..1} {4..1} ...`

`eval echo {1..1} {2..1} {3..1} ...` -> `echo 1 2 1 3 2 1 ...`

If the sublists must be delimited, then [25 bytes for `,`](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanBVZxaoqBb8T@1LDFHITU5I1@hutpQT0/FsFZPz7A2RkHnvyYXV5qCIRAbAbExEJv8BwA) or [26 bytes for newline](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxvyi1IDWxREHFUCE1OSNfoVolWls7M1ZPz7D2vyYXV5qCIRAbAbExEJuAaAOu/wA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 47 bytes

```
read*,i
print*,("{",(j,j=k,1,-1),"}",k=1,i)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vSk1M0dLJ5Cooyswr0dLRUKpW0tHI0smyzdYx1NE11NRRqlXSybY11MnU5ErNS/n/3wQA)

Could remove 8 chars by getting rid of printed brackets if anyone would believe that they are lists otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>22</s> 18 bytes

```arturo
$=>[map&=>[@&..1]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?yBKvvi)

Answer (score 3):

## [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
r=List.range 1
f=List.map(List.reverse<<r)<<r
```

[Try it on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/kR8mY5cqZkya1)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <strike>74</strike> <strike>73</strike> 51 bytes

`main=do i<-getLine;print[[x,x-1..1]|x<-[1..read i]]`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM882JV8h00Y3PbXEJzMv1bqgKDOvJDq6QqdC11BPzzC2psJGNxrIKkpNTFHIjI39/98EAA)

-22 bytes thanks to @79037662

Comment: I think you can remove the space after `reverse`

Comment: @mabel oh yeah, i had that in my code, just posted an old one, mb

Comment: You can remove the type annotation for main. Also, you could write a function instead of a full program.

Comment: 51 bytes: ```main=do i<-getLine;print[[x,x-1..1]|x<-[1..read i]]``` Removing unnecessary boilerplate, and using ```[x,x-1..1]``` instead of ```reverse```.

Comment: 26 bytes if it's just a function and not a whole program: https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjY6Ok8nT9dQT88wtibPRjcayKqIjf2fm5iZZ1tQlJlXopKmYPIfAA

Comment: Not completely familiar with the details of Haskell syntax - but I wonder if something like `i n=[1..n];(map(rev.i)).i` might work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
⟦₁⟧₁ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@aGh/NXw4kH26d8P@/yf8oAA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦₁     Ascending range from 1 to the input
    ᵐ  Map:
  ⟧₁     Descending range from 1 to the mapped element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 9 bytes

```
riroq<-pa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/KLMov9BGtyDx/38TAA)

```
ri  # Read int
ro  # Range [1,N]
q<- # Boxed reverse
pa  # Operate over ((1), (1 2), (1 2 3),...)
```

Alternative 9 byter, but this also has an empty list as the first element:

```
riroiT)<-
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 105 bytes

```go
func(n int)(o[][]int){for i:=1;i<=n;i++{J:=[]int{}
for j:=i;j>0;j--{J=append(J,j)}
o=append(o,J)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU69CsIwGNzzFMEpoa0oOEhjfIBM7qVDqE1JtF9CSF1Cn8SlCD6GD9K3sT863R133N3z1dhhxE5WN9nUuJUakG6d9WG7UW3YoIf0WPF3F1R2HLXqoCKANQRKbFEW5cyish7rnO-ZPnFgOkmiyPnixR7Npsm5Zua8YybLouDSuRquRKSG9sj-pU3FJH0dOg_9OviZ95ZThOKILn6qvANR5EAp-mWGYcUv)

Answer (score 2):

## shell with `seq` loop, 46 bytes

```sh
for n in `seq $1`;do seq -s\  -t'\n' $n 1;done
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 60 bytes

Without recursion:

```
n=>eval('for(a=[];n;a[--n]=b)for(b=[j=n];j-->1;b[n-j]=j);a')
```

Try it:

```js
f=n=>eval('for(a=[];n;a[--n]=b)for(b=[j=n];j-->1;b[n-j]=j);a')

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(4)));
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding recursion. Welcome CG.SE EM

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2 bytes

```
,$\,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWS3RUYnQgTKjIgoUmEAYA)

```
  Map
,  range
$   input (each line)
\  reverse
,   range
     it
```

Answer (score 2):

## Erlang 58 bytes

```
f(N)->[lists:reverse(lists:seq(1,X))||X<-lists:seq(1,N)].
```

Answer (score 2):

## [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack) alpha, 25 bytes

```
Reverse map IFrom1 IFrom1
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/funstack)!

#### Explanation

```
                   IFrom1  Inclusive range from 1 to the argument
            IFrom1         Inclusive range from 1 to each of those numbers
Reverse map                Reverse each sublist
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>69</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>48</s></sup> 46 bytes

```python
lambda n:[[*range(i+1,0,-1)]for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpaqygxLz1VI1PbUMdAR9dQMzYtv0ghUyEzTwEikacZ@7@gKDOvRCNNw0RT8z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
_MSMS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P9432Df4/39DAwA)

Comment: [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pzc@GEiaAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ!õ1
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SH1MQ&input=NAotUQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 54 bytes

```c
i,t;f(n){for(i=0;n/++i;)for(t=i;t;)printf("%d ",t--);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoAgEEDRvacQIZhBpRbtBg8TijGLNGRoE57d7O/ej/6McQx2QhkKvrk24LBRWa1lwp8SmITwblwkg1mSNk68R@pjHn0dXOCpnFC9Ss8y7Eiqjw8)

Comment: OMG I just wrote [this](https://tio.run/##FccxCoAwDADA3VdIQUioBQe32MdIJZKAUYpb6dsj3nYlnaW4KwkxGDa@K0heSDYj/KM5RiElfKrYyxCmYwyzpoTU/drFANvAsCIN3T8) and was looking to see if there was any other c answers before posting (not posting)! :-)

Comment: @Noodle9 I wrote this a long time ago but I made some improvements before writing my answer.

Comment: You can get this shorter if you use just one loop - [here's a start](https://tio.run/##DcfBCsIwDADQe7@ibAgJWwXBk1ndtyStqwFtx5xexr697t1ecCmE2moOr2982OGzRi3n571yL5Qg4zaVBdiLvxAPPpN452SUW9cxzovmdYLmFG3TC9Jej9s3a4Zf0YhmM/aQ4Ipk9voH).  But I got it even shorter with [recursive, non-loop approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199419/11259) :)

Comment: @Digital You can shorten yours with division -- I'll get back to it later if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 54 bytes

```php
for(;$i++<$argn;)$a[]=str_split($s=$i.$s);print_r($a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxCoAwDADAz2RoKTq5pcXNT4iULmpA2pDk/UZvOL7Z88r/55CAQCllaHJ1jND2o6hJVX7IAmgBmkEjslC3KgFaRPflHWw0uvq0fQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 20 bytes

```
.+
*
L$w`_+
$.&
O$^`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4vLR6U8IV6bS0VPjctfJS7h/38TAA) Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert the input to a string of `_`s of that length.

```
L$w`_+
$.&
```

List the lengths of all the possible substrings. The way Retina enumerates substrings means that the lengths are in the exact reverse of the desired order.

```
O$^`
```

Reverse the output line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
[:<@|.\1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61sHGr0Ygy1M/X@a3IpcKUmZ@QrpCmYwBhm/wE)

```
         i.    a list 0..n-1
        +      add
       1       one to it -> a list 1..n
      \        for each prefix of the list (1, 1 2, 1 2 3...)
    |.         reverse
   @           and
  <            box
[:             cap the fork
```

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 14 bytes

```
{{|1+!x}'1+!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qurrGUFuxolYdTP5PUzD5DwA)

```
{            }  a function with parameter x
           !x   a list 0..n-1
         1+     add one to it -> a list 1..n
 {     }'       apply this function to each of the elements of the above list
     !x         a list 0..n-1
   1+           add one to it -> a list 1..n
  |             reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒╒mx
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1ElAlFvx/78hlwmXoQEA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒     # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 ╒    # Convert each inner value to a list in the range [1, value]
  m   # Map over this list of lists:
   x  #  And reverse each inner list
      # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 42

I felt like there must be an elegant recursive solution to this.  This is the shortest I could come up with, though there is probably more room for golf.

- 4 bytes saved thanks to @S.S.Anne.

```c
f(n,m){n&&f(n-m/n,m%n+1)*printf("%d ",m);}
```

Initially, the function is called as `f(N, 1)`, where N is the input integer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYrLCoAgEADvfoUYhduToFvRv4RmLeQavS7Rt9vOaQbGVIsxMUEy221nOZyXxVCvY3SaSg8vZRlb5RuulIoW8v1AupxWqZWKj/6L3NJPSPoJaEG8QjJOd2ULvfjiDw)

Comment: `f(n-m/n` saves 3 bytes. Test it with higher inputs, though.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Thanks.  I like the symmetry of using `m/n` and `m%n` as well :).

Comment: In general any >= can be replaced by /. The same goes for <= but you reverse the arguments.

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##DYrLCoAgEADvfoUYhduToFvRv4RmLeQavS7Rt9vOaQbGVIsxMUEy221nOZyXxVCvY3SaSg8vZRlb5RuulIoW8v1AupxWqZWKj/6L3NJPSPoJaEG8QjJOd2ULvfjiDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 98 bytes

```java
n->{int a[][]=new int[n][],i=0,j;for(;i<n;)for(a[i]=new int[j=++i];j>0;)a[i-1][--j]=i-j;return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY69bsMwDIT3PAVHq4mEFOim2ECXAh06pZuhQfVPQNWmBIlOYQR@dldOC3ToRN59R@KcvVrp2s8Vx@Ajg8taTYyDetC7f14/UcPoaYPNYFOCN4sEtx1AmD4GbCCx5TyuHlsYMyvOHJEutQEbL0ncowCvxC@/r05IXJvaVNBDuZKsbtkAu1kldV@wYcrigOXx4HTvY6HxRFpsm63xL@XK/R6NdtVRiwzko6mldKZE6XTseIoEVi@rvjc4z4m7UfmJVcgFeaDiOUY7J9V2XXj3P7WLXtkQhrl4EkJsh8tuWb8B)

Answer (score 1):

## Coffeescript, 29 bytes

```
r=(x)->[[y..1]for y in[1..x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85PS0tNLU4uyiwoMfr/v8hWo0JT1y46ulJPzzA2Lb9IoVIhMy/aUE@vIjb2f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpGGiabmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 145 bytes

```sql
WITH a(n)as(SELECT number FROM spt_values
WHERE'p'=type)SELECT string_agg(@+1-a.n,' ')FROM
a,a b WHERE a.n<=@ and b.n<a.n
GROUP BY b.n ORDER BY 1
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1197620/reversed-iotas)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 bytes

```
RmRr|u
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=RmRr%7Cu&i=4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
řĐř-⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MwjE47O1H3UuOv/fxMA)

Code worked on input of 3:

| Code | Stack | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `ř` | [1,2,3] | implicit input; **ř**angify [1,2,...,n] |
| `Đ` | [1,2,3] [1,2,3] | **Đ**uplicate |
| `ř` | [1,2,3] [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]] | **ř**angify |
| `-` | [[0],[1,0],[2,1,0]] | subtract |
| `⁺` | [[1],[2,1],[3,2,1]] | increment; implicit print |

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ɾɾR
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvsm+UiIsIiIsIjQiXQ==)

Can't believe I never answered this challenge despite the fact it was asked by one of the greatest golfers I ever knew

### Explained

```
ɾɾR
ɾ   # the range [1, input] 
 ɾ  # and that for each item in the range
  R # vectorised reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp 2](https://github.com/dloscutoff/tinylisp2), 14 bytes

```lisp
(.(p m to1)1to
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/tinylisp2)! Example session:

```lisp
tl2> (.(p m to1)1to
(() (_arg) ((p m to1) (1to _arg)))
tl2> (d F _)
F
tl2> (F 5)
((1) (2 1) (3 2 1) (4 3 2 1) (5 4 3 2 1))
```

#### Explanation

```lisp
(.(p m to1)1to)
  (p      )      ; Partially apply
     m           ;  the map function
       to1       ;  to the to1 function (given N, return the list of numbers from
                 ;  N down to 1)
(.            )  ; Compose that with
           1to   ; the 1to function (given N, return the list of numbers from
                 ; 1 up to N)
```

Thus: take one argument `N`; generate the range from 1 to `N`; then for each of those numbers, generate the range from it down to 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.6+, 42 bytes

```swift
{(1...$0).map{n->[_]in(1...n).reversed()}}
```

Type information (here `->[_]`) is required. Without it, the return type is `[ReversedCollection<ClosedRange<_>>]`, as the range primitive's `.reversed()` method is lazy by default.

[SwiftFiddle link](https://swiftfiddle.com/f7cfj6sgdnh7rkqcy3huc6aqci) with both ways (with and without type info) to highlight the difference.

This technically isn't even full type info, as the actual type of number used is left unspecified, as `_`. It doesn't even necessarily have to be a builtin type as long as it meets certain requirements. With full generics, the function might look something like this (ungolfed):

```swift
func f<T: Strideable & ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(_ n: T) -> [[T]]
where T.Stride: SignedInteger {
    return (1 ... n).map { i in
        (1 ... i).reversed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), `-p` 12 bytes

```
Fl\,aO R\,lx
```

How?

```
Fl\,aO R\,lx  : One arg; int
    a         : First input(max for range)
Fl            : For each in:
  \,a         : Range from 1 to a
        \,l     : Range from 1 to l(int from range)
       R        : Reverse
     O          : Output
           x  : Trigger output
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGbFxcLGFPIFJcXCxseCIsIiIsIiIsIjEwIC1wIl0=)

Comment: This is super late, but here's a 10-byte version: [`Fl\,aPl-,l`](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGbFxcLGFQbC0sbCIsIiIsIiIsIjEwIC1wIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>27</s> 21 bytes

```julia
~n=1:n.|>i->[i:-1:1;]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7P1tAqT6/GLlPXLjrTStfQytA69n9BUWZeSU6enkadueZ/AA)

-6 bytes (!!) thanks to MarcMush: Replace `map` with a broadcast `.|>`

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7P1tAqT6/GLlPXLjrTStfQytA69n9KZnFBTmKlRp255n8A) (tip in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219504/98541))

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
RRᵐ↔
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FiuCgh5unfCobcqS4qTkYqjggoUmEAYA)

```
R       Range
 R      Range
  ᵐ     Map
   ↔    Reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>19</s> 13 bytes

```ruby
:+|:*&(:+|:~)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWa620a6y01DRAVJ0mRGxZgYJbtEkshLNgAYQGAA)

### Explanation

```
:+ | :* & (:+ | :~)
:+ |                 # Range 1..input, then
     :* & (       )  # Map with...
           :+ | :~   #   Range 1..n, then reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RRṃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS4OCHu5sXlKclFwMFVmw0BTCAAA)

##### Explanation

```python
RRṃ  # Implicit input   ->  5
R    # Push [1..input]  ->  [1 2 3 4 5]
 R   # Push [1..each]   ->  [[1] [1 2] [1 2 3] [1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 4 5]]
  ṃ  # Reverse each     ->  [[1] [2 1] [3 2 1] [4 3 2 1] [5 4 3 2 1]]
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 7 bytes

```
R*\,\,a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhbLg7RidGJ0EiE8qODiaBOYPAA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
R*\,\,a
      a  ; Command-line argument
    \,   ; Inclusive range from 1 to that number
  \,     ; Inclusive range from 1 to each of those numbers
R*       ; Reverse each
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 7 bytes

```
¯⍚⇌⍚⇡⇡¯
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAgwq_ijZrih4zijZrih6Hih6HCrwoKRiA0CkYgNgo=)

```
¯⍚⇌⍚⇡⇡¯
      ¯  # negate
     ⇡   # range
   ⍚⇡    # range w/ boxing
 ⍚⇌      # reverse each
¯        # negate
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, 44 bytes

```swift
let f={(1...$0).map{(1...$0).reversed()+[]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
ＩＥＮ⮌Ｅ⊕ι⊕μ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQMMzr6C0xK80Nym1SENTRyEotSy1qDgVKpVclJqbmleSmqKRCZRD5udqgoH1//8m/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  Ｎ         Input as a number
 Ｅ          Map over implicit 0-indexed range
      ι     Current index
     ⊕      Incremented
    Ｅ       Map over implicit 0-indexed range
        μ   Inner index
       ⊕    Incremented
   ⮌        Reversed
Ｉ           Cast to string for implicit print
```

There are other ways of getting the inner range such as `InclusiveRange(1, Incremented(i))` and `Range(1, Plus(2, i))` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 36 bytes

```clj
#(for[i(range %)](range(inc i)0 -1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappD2X1kjLb8oOlOjKDEvPVVBVTMWwtLIzEtWyNQ0UNA11NT8r8mlUVCUp6CRpmCiqanwHwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 37 bytes

```
{(1..it).map{(it downTo 1).toList()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxCsMwEAS/suVdERFDKhPLdcBlPiCwBUfkk3EuSWH8dllOs8XMsK9sSbR8Q0JsQQ81xsVjkLfd/1OJ9@jKRo1zYuzmsGwkhjH/9JnRsLN8lsT7XuJHMQdRYnRYVlFLSpHWKYyD6ETc17peVt@3uDKX2wE)